# Commodore 64 board dimensions

Tags: commodore-64, case, homemade

What are the dimensions of the C64 motherboard? I am specifically asking this because I am considering using a 64C case (these still seem to be in production) for an 8-bit homebrew machine. I wonder if it is possible to design a board in such a way that it would fit the Commodore case as well as a standard something-ATX PC case.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seams more like a blatant advertisement for the linked site than a real question. After all, if you're looking for dimensions not the C64 board (there are several, different sized BTW) is important, but room and mountings the case offers - so as it's seller.

Comment: I removed the link, I am not at all affiliated with them

Comment: @Raffzahn I was hoping for someone to just measure the size of a C64 motherboard for me so that I can estimate if using the case was at all feasible for my project without going out and buying one.

Comment: But which board? There are are least 3 C64 boards with different dimension. You need to look at the case you want to use, not some arbitrary board. And equally important you need to check mounting holes, or do you want to have it rattling around? So it's the case you need to measure.

Comment: @Raffzahn -- The C-64C cases are designed to accept all boards. Commodore themselves were happy to install whatever boards (and keyboards) they had lying around, that's why there are so many variations.

Comment: @Raffzahn of course I need to measure the case, but knowing the size of an original board tells me how large of a board will definetly fit in there. I need at least 244x170mm for my idea to work. Now that I verified that the original boards are larger than that, I will go ahead and order a case to do the exact measurements. I hope this explains why I asked for the board dimensions, those are enough for me to decide if it is worth for me to buy the case, and easy to measure for someone who regularly works on C64 machines unlike me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several revisions of the C-64 board (see, e.g., [here](http://www.cbmhardware.de/show.php?r=1&id=25/Die%20Platinen%20des%20C64) , or [here](https://www.c64-wiki.de/wiki/Hauptplatine)), with two major form factors: the old "long board" and the new "short board". The long board (which I happen to have on my bench right now) is approximately 39cm wide and 18cm long, the short board is just as wide, but a little, well, shorter.

If you need exact dimensions and drill points, you could look at some of the replica PCBs that are floating around on the net, like [these](https://github.com/bwack/KU-14194HB-RevB-KiCad), maybe even use the board files as a basis for laying out your PCB.

One thing to keep in mind when designing your own PCB is that, while the long board does fit into a C-64C case, there's not much vertical clearance on the lower end - just barely enough for a socketed DIP IC, so don't place anything tall there.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! 18 cm is much wider than what I would have guessed. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @StefanPaulNoack - added a note on vertical clearance, something to keep in mind for your own system.